# Android-to-web app-to-iPhone, without Xcode

Tags: android, ruby, web-applications

I have released a native Android application, which I built in Android Studio. After a rocky start, it is now doing alright in the PlayStore.

I hope to release an iPhone version soon, and I am considering my options. 
My general approach will be redeveloping the project as a web application using Ruby on Rails, then converting that to an iPhone app somehow.

I am writing to ask more about this final step. What cost-effective ways are there to convert a web application to iPhone format?
 I am aware I will need $99 for the Apple developer programme, and I would like to keep my overall costs close to that amount. I had thought of using PhoneGap. Are there any extra steps between PhoneGap and publishing on the App store?

Extra information, which might help contextualise my situation:
I do not have an Apple devices or software for development or testing. I’m not the Prince of Monaco, so I do not intend to spend on these things anytime soon. My app is called Victoriana, and it is a Choose-Your-Own-Adventure/ text adventure game. Pretty basic, really.

This is my first real project, and I first came into developing through tutorials and Android Studio. 
It would also be my first time coding a web application or using Ruby, but for converting this non-complex project I am happy to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app requires a lot of database interaction, Rails is probably too heavy-weight for what you need. If you're set on building a web app in Ruby then [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is much simpler and a better option for beginners, but again depending on the complexity of the game, how you persist state etc, you might actually be better off with Javascript and a single-page app framework.

There really is no developing for Apple products without running macOS, but it is possible to do this within a virtual machine on a Windows PC.

Comment: Thankyou for the tip about Sinatra. The app only uses text and Jpeg images, so the beginner's option is probably best for me right now.